# Looping the Sum of numbers (Inputs) in C

Tags: c, while-loop

Give the c code for a loop that computes and displays a sum of numbers that the user enters.  The loop should prompt the user for input until the user enters -335 and then exit and display the final sum.

This is what I have. Why does it not print (exit the loop) when I enter -335? It just keeps asking me to input a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{

int userNum;
printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
scanf("%d", &userNum);

while (userNum != -335){
    printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &userNum);
    userNum += userNum;

}

printf("%d", userNum);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are *continuously* overwriting the `userNum` loosing both the original input *and* the calculated sum. You should rethink your logic.

Comment: When you scanf into userNum, you're replacing the value that was in there before. There's no summing taking place. You're simply adding the number you just entered to itself. You should have a separate place to store the input or the sum.

Comment: You need *two* variables: the number input, and the sum.

Comment: BTW, you want `-335` but checking for `335`...

Comment: Ok I see where i went wrong thanks everyone

Comment: oh ye i changed it from -335 to 335 to check something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional variable to keep track of the sum instead. Your current method keeps overwriting it:

So add a line:

```
int userNum;
int sum = 0; // sum holds total variable
```

and you add and change here:

```
while (userNum != 335){
    printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &userNum);
    sum += userNum;
}

 printf("%d", sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

userNum changes after you have input it, in the statement `userNum += userNum;`. -335 plus -335 is -670, not 335.

Comment: thank you. Do you know how i can fix it? im new to programming

Answer (score 1):

```
  while (userNum != 335){
printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
scanf("%d", &userNum);
userNum += userNum;
```

You are losing the input provided by user in the last statement.Use a separate variable to store result.

```
 int ans=0;
 while (userNum != -335){
printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
scanf("%d", &userNum);
ans += userNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

your program is hanging in a while loop forever because there is even no luck to break the loop because there's no integer * 2 = -335, there's only float (-167.5).

- there's one in million chance to break the loop IF you declare userNum as float so inside the loop enter -167.5:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void)
  {

      float userNum;  
      printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
      scanf("%G", &userNum);

      while (userNum != -335){
          printf("Please enter an integer:\n"); // enter -167.5
          scanf("%G", &userNum);
          userNum += userNum; // -167.5 + (-167.5) = -335 which will cause while to exit

      }

      printf("%G", userNum); // -335

      return 0;
  }
  ```

to solve your problem declare a new variable let's say sum then sum userNum and store the result in it. so userNum is still unchanged while evaluating so if it was -335 while will exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{

    int userNum;
    int sum = 0; // (very important) initialize in order not to sum gabage value 

    printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &userNum);

    while (userNum != -335){
        printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
        scanf("%d", &userNum);
        sum += userNum;

    }

    printf("%d", sum);
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```